# Change the data range of a graph

Tags: excel, vba

I've got the following code where LastRow = 108
All I want to do is take a chat that was already created (Chart 1) and change the range to be B2:C108

```
chartData = "B2:C" & LastRow
    Worksheets("MachineData").ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart.SetSourceData Source:=chartData
```

but I keep getting this error

[image]

How could I fix this?

Comment: Please make your question into a [mre], currently there's not much details on the cause of this problem,.

Comment: Looks like you're providing a string when the method is looking for a range object.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution, I just had to tell VBA from what sheet I wanted to take my data

```
Worksheets("MachineData").ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart.SetSourceData Source:=Worksheets("MachineData").Range("B2:C" & LastRow)
```

Comment: It's not working only because you provided the worksheet. It's working because `Worksheets("MachineData").Range("B2:C" & LastRow)` is a range object and `chartData = "B2:C" & LastRow` is a string. `Set chartData = Worksheets("MachineData").Range("B2:C" & LastRow)` and `Worksheets("MachineData").ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart.SetSourceData Source:=chartData` would also work.